# Anaconda3 Custom Install Location: 'conda' Not Working

Tags: python, windows, path, anaconda, conda

Through carelessness, I have two Anaconda install locations: one on C:\Anaconda3\ (on a smallish SSD with Windows 10 installed) and one on X:\Anaconda3\ (on a large HDD with no OS installed), and I would like to keep the one on X as my only installation. I have X:\Anaconda3, X:\Anaconda3\Scripts, and X:\Anaconda3\Library\bin folders in my PATH.

I've noticed is that I can't used any `conda` commands with my X:\ installation in the PATH variable. I get the usual "conda is not a recognized command" error. But if I change the drive of the folders in PATH to C:\, suddenly everything works great. I've also tried making my current directory be on X:\ while running these commands, and `conda` still doesn't work.

How might I fix this issue? There must be something I'm missing about how the PATH variable or the `conda` command works. Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear from what you explain what's in you `PATH` and what you're typing. Do you literally have `\Anaconda3` in your PATH? If so, that's a path relative to whatever happens to be the current working drive. For example, if you're in a cmd prompt, and it says `D:\>`, and you try to run `conda`, it'll look for `D:\Anaconda3\conda.exe`, which doesn't exist. Also, does explicitly typing `X:\Anaconda3\conda` work? (Or whichever of the three directories `conda` is in.) Are you sure you have a valid installation?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you don't want to simplify things by just uninstalling both copies of Conda, and reinstalling the X: one (or at least uninstalling the C: one)?

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, I should've been more explicit. I have all three folders as X: drive in my system PATH variable, e.g. "X:\Anaconda3". I think you may be onto something with trying to explicitly find `conda.exe`. I went looking for it in both installs and I have `conda.exe` in C:\Anaconda3\Scripts, and I have `conda.exe.c~` in X:\Anaconda3\Scripts. I'm not sure what the `.c~` is for, but I have a hunch that it's a pointer to the same file on C: drive? Maybe completely uninstalling both installs and starting over completely is what I need just to set everything straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@abarnert Thanks to you I managed to find the issue.

On looking into both install paths, I found that only the C:\ installation had `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`. The X:\ installation had `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe.c~`. I still don't know what that file's for, but I assume it pointed to the `conda.exe` on C:. Anyway, a complete uninstall of both locations followed by a fresh install on X:\ got everything to work. I can now run commands like `conda env list` and similar using the installation on X:\

Thanks again!